# ODataQueryOptions always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, devextreme

It's my first time that i work with ODataQueryOptions and don't know to make an asp.net web api 2 method GET work with this, i have this code in my project:

## WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
        ...
    }
}
```

## ApiController

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/dtoobjects")]
public class DtoObjectsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DtoObjectManager m_dtoObjectManager = new DtoObjectManager();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<DtoObject> Get(ODataQueryOptions<DtoObject> options)
    {
        var dtoObjects = m_dtoObjectManager.Get(...);

        IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(dtoObjects.AsQueryable());

        return results as IQueryable<DtoObject>;
    }
}
```

## AjaxRequest (DevExtreme custom store)

```
var store = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
    load: function(loadOptions) {
        var d = $.Deferred();

        var params = {};

        //Getting filter options
        if (loadOptions.filter) {
            params.filter = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.filter);
        }

        //Getting sort options
        if (loadOptions.sort) {
            params.sort = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.sort);
        }

        //Getting group options
        if (loadOptions.group) {
            params.group = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.group);
        }

        //skip and take are used for paging
        params.skip = loadOptions.skip; //A number of records that should be skipped
        params.take = loadOptions.take; //A number of records that should be taken

        //If the select expression is specified
        if (loadOptions.select) {
            params.select = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.select);
        }

        //If a user typed something in dxAutocomplete, dxSelectBox or dxLookup
        if (loadOptions.searchValue) {
            params.searchValue = loadOptions.searchValue;
            params.searchOperation = loadOptions.searchOperation;
            params.searchExpr = loadOptions.searchExpr;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/dtoobjects",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                d.resolve(response, { totalCount: response.length });
            }
        });
        return d.promise();
    }
```

When ajax request fires the GET method, "ODataQueryOptions options" always is empty!

[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: can you show the request url after you constructed the queryoptions?

Comment: http://.../api/dtoobjects?Skip=0&Top=5

Comment: http://.../api/groups?filter=[["param1"%2C"contains"%2C"unknown"]%2C"and"%2C["param2"%2C"%3D"%2C"something"]]&Skip=0&Top=5

Comment: in OData the queryopiton should contains $, like $filter=...&$top=..